# unable to launch android emulator in super micro systems

Tags: android, android-emulator

I'm getting the follow error while launch the android emulators.

failed to create drawable
   getGLES1ExtensionString: Could not create GLES 1.x Pbuffer!
   Failed to obtain GLES 1.x extensions string!
   Could not initialize emulated framebuffer

**System details:**

**OS** : Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
**Processor** : Intel® Xeon(R) CPU E5-2630 v3 @ 2.40GHz × 16 
**memory**: 125.8 GiB
**Video**: ASPEED AST2400 BMC

please find the below link for complete system configuration.

http://www.supermicro.com/products/system/1u/6018/sys-6018r-mt.cfm

please help me to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance for your help.
Tirupathi Rao.